# An MCQ for finding the extremal of the functional $J = \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y^{'})$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Consider a functional

$$J = \int_{a}^{b} F(x, y, y^{'}),$$ where $F(x, y, y^{'}) = \frac{1 + y^{2}}{(y^{'})^2}$ for admissible function $y(x).$ Which of the following are extremals for $J$?

1. $y(x) = A\sin x $
2. $y(x) = A\sinh x + B\cosh x$
3. $y(x) = A\sinh(Ax + B)$
4. $y(x) = A\sin x + B\cos x$

I use Cauchy Euler equation. But it does not give me any direction to justify the option(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extremals of functional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614754/extremals-of-functional)

Comment: @JessePFrancis I think the answer to the present one is better; it just needs an upvote so that the question can be closed in the opposite direction.

Comment: @NormalHuman, I picked this as duplicate because the other was older, and had some personal effort show there, which is not there here!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Strictly speaking, to have a well-posed variational problem, one should impose boundary conditions. We will assume Dirichlet boundary conditions in what follows.
2. Note that the Lagrangian $$F(x, y, y^{'}) = \frac{y^2+1}{(y^{\prime})^2}$$ does *not* depend explicit on the independent variable $x$.
3. We can therefore use [the](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BeltramiIdentity.html) Beltrami [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) to get a first integral.
   $$\exists C:~~C~=~ \left(y^{\prime}\frac{\partial }{\partial y^{\prime}} -1\right)F~=~-3F. $$
4. In other words,
   $$ y^{\prime}~=~K \sqrt{y^2+1} , \qquad K~:=~\sqrt{-\frac{3}{C}}. $$
5. Separation of variables: $$ \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}~=~K\mathrm{d} x.$$
6. Integrate: $~~{\rm arsinh} (y) ~=~ K (x-x_0).$
7. Isolate: $~~y~=~\sinh\left(K (x-x_0)\right).$